# How to add multiple newlines at end of a file in ubuntu using sed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sed

Input File

```
ABC
DEF
```

Output File

```
ABC
DEF


GHI
```

I am using

```
sed -i -e '$a\\GHI ' input.txt
```

but it adds GHI but not 2 preceding new lines

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've tagged `linux`, am assuming you have GNU sed and that `\n` is recognized

```
$ cat ip.txt 
ABC
DEF
$ sed '$a\\n\nGHI' ip.txt
ABC
DEF


GHI
```

Add `-i` option once it is working

GNU sed doesn't require `\` to be used after `a` command but has its own use cases. Hence the `\\n` at start in previous example. See [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands) for details

```
$ echo 'foo' | sed '$a123'
foo
123
$ echo 'foo' | sed '$a 123'
foo
123
$ echo 'foo' | sed '$a\ 123'
foo
 123
```

Also, this can be done easily without needing `sed`

```
$ printf '\n\nGHI\n' >> ip.txt 
$ cat ip.txt 
ABC
DEF


GHI
```

Answer (score 0):

use **\n** to change line
for example,a file 1.txt

```
11111
222222

sed -i '$s/$/\n\n\n333333\n4444444444/' 1.txt
```

explain:first '$'  means last line of file,second '$' means end of line.

result:

```
11111
222222


333333
4444444444
```

Comment: As i mentioned in the question I want to 2 new lines before string. The correct output should be
11111<br>
222222<br><br><br>
333333<br>
4444444444

Comment: @Tabish Rizvi oh,it is really no difference, if you know '\n' is the new line ,you can add many new line as you want .between 2222and 3333, 1 line or 2 line ,or 3 line ,or even more , there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!b;G;G;aGHI' file
```

Append a couple of newlines to the pattern space, then append `GHI` to the output stream.

N.B. The pattern space is printed before the output stream.

or explicitly:

```
sed '$G;$G;$aGHI' file
```